# I need to select all rows from user table where row does not have value in join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have three tables:

Users, Groups and GroupsUsers

User table:

> id: 1 username: admin
>
> id: 2 username: barry

Groups Table:

> id: 102 name: Administrator
>
> id: 103 name: Site User

GroupsUser (Join table between Users and Groups)

> id: 1 user_id: 1 group_id: 102
>
> id: 2 user_id: 2 group_id: 103
>
> id: 3 user_id: 1 group_id: 103

---

Now the problem I have is: I want to select ALL users from Users table that do NOT belong to 'Administrator' group. What I have attempted is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `Users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `GroupsUsers` AS `GroupsUser` 

ON (`GroupsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND `GroupsUser`.`group_id` NOT in ( 102 ) ) 

WHERE 
 (
  NOT ( `GroupsUser`.`group_id` IN ( 102 )
 ) 
)
```

For some reason, this still returns the Administrator account. What I want to do, is return JUST 'barry', or in this case - a COUNT of '1', not '2'.

Comment: its return 2 because you have 2 rows when u make join with groupuser, id: 2 user_id: 2 group_id: 103 & id: 3 user_id: 1 group_id: 103

Comment: Maybe I was not extremely clear - I am trying to do a select on the group_id being a value. I want to select users that ONLY have that row in the corresponding table. I want to disregard users that have that row and other rows. Does that make sense or am I still being unclear?

Comment: No you are not clear at all. Given your data, NO user matches that criteria, because only user:1 is an admin, but user 1 is ALSO a site user.

Comment: do **NOT** repost.  [Edit to fix your errors](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5529217/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to get users that are only "Site User" and at the same time they are not "Adminstrator"

So, if a user belongs to both groups, you want to exclude him from the result...

if that's what you are trying to do, try this:

```
SELECT `User`.*
FROM `Users` AS `User`
WHERE `User`.id NOT IN (
   SELECT `User2`.id
   FROM `Users` AS `User2`, `GroupsUsers` AS `GroupsUser`
   WHERE
        ( `GroupUser`.`user_id` = `User2`.`id` )
       AND
        ( `GroupUser`.`group_id` = 102 )
)
```

hope this helps...

good luck with your development...

Comment: you are welcome.  
this is even more efficient than JOINs..  
JOINs are usually expensive operations...  
so try to avoid them whenever you can !

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM Users AS User
LEFT JOIN GroupsUsers AS GroupsUser
    ON GroupsUser.user_id = User.id AND GroupsUser.group_id = 102
WHERE GroupsUser.user_id IS NULL
```

The left join attempts to find the user in the GroupUsers table, in the group 102 (Administrators).  If the match is found, `GroupsUser.user_id` is not null, so the reverse condition `WHERE GroupsUser.user_id IS NULL` keeps only where the match cannot be found, i.e. user is not an administrator.

For the comment "I want to select users that ONLY have that row in the corresponding table", which is neither the same as the question body, nor the title

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM Users AS User
LEFT JOIN GroupsUsers AS GroupsUser1
    ON GroupsUser1.user_id = User.id AND GroupsUser1.group_id = 102
LEFT JOIN GroupsUsers AS GroupsUser2
    ON GroupsUser2.user_id = User.id AND GroupsUser2.group_id <> 102
WHERE GroupsUser2.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: @Barry / I created the tables and records and tested it, returning count of 1.

Comment: As my comment above states, I need to select all users that match ONLY that value in the join table. I want to disregard users that have more than just that row.

Comment: Voting this down because you misread the question is not exactly called for. The answer submitted does not answer the question at all, it does the opposite of what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Barry  Time for you to learn how to express your question and examples properly. The answer here gives "1", per your sample answer, against your *exact* sample data.

Comment: I would like to select users that match only given value, and exclude the users that match that value in addition to others. What is poorly phrased with that?